# nestacms and webbynode rapp

Tags: sinatra, rack, webbynode, nestacms

I would like to deploy a [nestacms](http://nestacms.com/) blog on [webbynode](http://webbynode.com/) by using the webbynode gem as allways I do with rails. Altough Webbynode seem to support Sinatra and Rack application easily, I get a **WARNING** during deployment stating that the application will not run smoothly because it **lacks a public folder**:

```
WARNING: Missing public folder in your Rack app, it'll not run smoothly!
```

Actually the rapid application development (RAPP webbynode gem) sets the need of a public folder into the **Nginx configuration**:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name super_duper_blog.webbyapp.com ;
      root /var/rapp/super_duper_blog/public/;
      passenger_enabled on;
  }
```

Instead this is my nestacms `config.ru`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

Bundler.require(:default)

require 'nesta/app'

Nesta::App.root = ::File.expand_path('.', ::File.dirname(__FILE__))
run Nesta::App
```

It would be nice if the author and SO user [Graham Ashton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158841/graham-ashton) could jump in and help me. Anyway, how could I get around the problem?

**UPDATE**

After creating the project, with nesta new you nedd to:

1. Create a `public` folder manually
2. Add some content in it. Say for ex. `humnans.txt` and `favicon.ico`
3. `git add .` and `git commit -m "added public with humans and favicon"`
4. wn push

And your nestacms website will go on line at a private webbynode address (blog.webbyapp.com)
Then you can use wn changedns www.example.com to make your site available for the masses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used webbynode, so I'm not sure quite how its set up. Have you seen the Nginx passenger install guide? Could be useful:

http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app

It says you need public/ and tmp/, so I'm inclined to believe it.

Did you try making these directories yourself? Does the site actually start up? How are you deploying your site to the webbynode?

All my Sinatra apps are deployed with Vlad (see http://effectif.com/articles/deploying-sinatra-with-vlad) which takes care of creating public/ and tmp/ for you. It also touches tmp/restart.txt (see the Passenger guide I linked to above) when you deploy a new version of the site if you tell it that you're using Passenger. Capistrano also works fine (and is more extensively documented these days).

Comment: Although I've already tried creating the public folder, for unknown reasons It was not deployed (wn push) to the server. Adding a fake file in it did the trick. BTW with webbynode there is no need to use a deploy tool, the webbynode gem has everything you need. 1. nesta new 2. wn init 3. wn push 4. No step 4, nesta is on line!

Comment: found the reason here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository